# what type of parser have been used in solr

Tags: solr, edismax, dismax

If I have not specified ***defType*** in solr query which parser will be used, whether DisMax or EDisMax ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before Solr 1.3, the Standard Request Handler called the standard query parser as the default query parser. In versions since Solr 1.3, the Standard Request Handler calls the DisMax query parser as the default query parser.

http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser

Answer (score 0):

The defType parameter selects the query parser that Solr should use to process the main query parameter (q) in the request. For example:defType=dismax

According solr 6.6,If no defType param is specified, then by default, the The Standard Query Parser is used. (eg: defType=lucene)

same question is also asked in [what is solr's default query parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23115781/what-is-solrs-default-query-parser/47947661)

reference : https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/common-query-parameters.html