# what is solr's default query parser

Tags: parsing, solr, lucene

i am confused by these words in the solr document:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser

> Before Solr 1.3, the Standard Request Handler called the standard
>   query parser as the default query parser. In versions since Solr 1.3,
>   the Standard Request Handler calls the DisMax query parser as the
>   default query parser.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser

> The q parameter does not support wildcard characters such as *.

so i download solr 4.7.2, unzip it

checking that i have

```
  <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
```

in `solr-4.7.2/example/solr/collection1/conf/solrconfig.xml`, by default.

then, i index this document

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<add>
  <doc boost="1.0">
        <field name="id">item1</field>
    </doc>
</add>
```

but

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=id:it*
```

finds the document,

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=id:it*defType=dismax
```

finds no item

so looks like standard query parser is the default instead of the dismax query parser?

Answer (score 2):

The default is defined in your solrconfig.xml file. The default solrconfig.xml file that comes with 4.7.2 has the following entry:

edismax

This means that the default is the extended dismax query parser. http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax

Comment: where is that? could you please point me out?

i search "edismax" but only find it under the config of "/browse" and "/clustering"

Answer (score 0):

It looks me standard query parser is the default instead of the dismax query parser.
 But we can specify default query parser for any solr(ver 4 ) request handler.

below is some config entry from solrConfig.xml file

```
    <requestHandler name="/query" class="solr.SearchHandler">
         <lst name="defaults">
           <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
           <int name="rows">20</int>
           <str name="defType">edismax</str>
           <str name="wt">json</str>
         </lst>
      </requestHandler>
```

Comment: The defType parameter selects the query parser that Solr should use to process the main query parameter (q) in the request. 
For example:defType=dismax
If no defType param is specified, then by default, the The Standard Query Parser is used. (eg: defType=lucene)

reference :
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/common-query-parameters.html

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment to your initial question, but nagendra has it essentially right, although you are using `/query` rather than `/select` which he is defining as a `requestHandler` in his segment from `solrconfig.xml`.

You are also missing an `&` in your url before your `defType` so it will be treated as part of your search string, not as a separate parameter.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=id:it*&defType=dismax
```

will not return results because it will use the dismax parser which doesn't support `*`, but,

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=id:it*&defType=edismax
```

will give a result as it is instead using `edismax`.

As of the time of writing the page you refer to has been replaced with the following which refers to the standard query parser being the default, so perhaps it has reverted?

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-standard-query-parser.html

Comment: Thank you cccnrc for the edits to make my post more readable: much appreciated. I will get there eventually!